# Flask Python reloading object multiple times

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that gets a json file and loads it into memory, then displays the data to the end user.  Every time that I hit refresh or navigate through the site, the fetch data occurs again.  Thus, reloading n results into lists.  Example, if there were 5 services, then there would be 10 on the next reload, 15 on the next, etc.  How can I make it where the object is destroyed on page exit?

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    from organization import Organization
    print("run the loop")
    content = Organization()

    return render_template('index.html', content=content)
```

This is the class

```
class Organization:

services = []

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    base_url = 'url'
    domain = 'xyz.com'

    r = requests.get(url=base_url + domain)
    organization = json.loads(r.text)

    for s in organization['_service_benefit']:

       self.services[s['service_id']].append(ServiceBenefit(s_headline = s['headline'], s_content = s['content'], s_service_id=s['service_id']))
```

Comment: you cannot .... a page just renders, and then its done ... unless you establish some sort of websocket connection ... its probably an easier thing to save the "service" thing in a session variable and on load if that exists kill it first

Comment: This isn't really that much of a flask problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initializing one Organization object out of `index` and render template with that every time? I am assuming your organization data does not change. If this does not work, try placing services in `__init__`. This means each instance has its own services instance, which should solve the problem. You do not need to automatically delete it at all.

The code would look something like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.services = []
    ...
    for s in organization['_service_benefit']:
       self.services[s['service_id']].append(ServiceBenefit(s_headline = s['headline'], s_content = s['content'], s_service_id=s['service_id']))
```

For the second implementation, and for the first, your main program would look like this

```py
from organization import Organization
org = Organization()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", content=org)
```

In any case, a class may not be the best solution here unless you are using the `Organization` class for something else other than (apparently) displaying service benefits. A simple list of `ServiceBenefit` objects may suffice.